# Java: How to add objects from List<T> to Map (Key: Enum, value List<T>)

Tags: java, list, collections, java-stream

I'm trying to add objects from the `List<Farm>` to `Map<Animal, List<Farm>>`

```
public class Farm {
    private String farmName;
    private EnumSet<Animal> animals = EnumSet.noneOf(Animal.class);
    /* ... */
}

Farm f1 = new Farm("Farm A", EnumSet.of(Animal.CAT, Animal.DOG, Animal.DUCK));
Farm f2 = new Farm("Farm B", EnumSet.of(Animal.PIG, Animal.CAT, Animal.HORSE));
Farm f3 = new Farm("Farm C", EnumSet.of(Animal.DUCK));
```

Task 1: add Objects to `List<Farm>`

```
List<Farm> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(f1);
list.add(f2);
list.add(f3);
```

Task 2: Add the objects from list to a map (Key: `Animal`, Value: `List <Farm>`) I did this task in this way:

```
Map<Animal, List<Farm>> map = new HashMap<>();

for(Farm farm: list) {
    for(Animal an: farm.getAnimals()) {
        if(!map.containsKey(an)) {
            List<Farm> new_list = new ArrayList<>();
            new_list.add(farm);
            map.put(an, new_list);
        }else {     
            List<Farm> old_list = map.get(an);
            if(!old_list.contains(farm)) {
                old_list.add(farm);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a second / more efficient solution?
Something like this:

```
Map<Animal, List<Farm>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Farm::getAnimals)));
```

This does not work because `getAnimals` returns an `EnumSet<Animal>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to stay with the loop, but modernize it:

```
Map<Animal, List<Farm>> map = new EnumMap<>(Animal.class);
for(Farm farm: list)
    for(Animal an: farm.getAnimals())
        map.computeIfAbsent(an, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(farm);
```

In your loop, `add(farm)` redundantly appeared in both branches, as you always add it to the `List`. Then, [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) allows to eliminate the conditional, as it will return an existing value or construct a new value, put and return it. The `groupingBy` collector also uses this method internally.

Using a Stream operation for the same has the disadvantage that you need a temporary holder for two values, e.g.

```
Map<Animal, List<Farm>> map = list.stream()
    .flatMap(farm -> farm.getAnimals().stream()
        .map(animal -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(animal, farm)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
        () -> new EnumMap<>(Animal.class),
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

I started from the opposite side, but I suppose it's helpful

```
    Map<Animal, List<Farm>> map = Arrays.stream(Animal.values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(an -> an, an -> list.stream().filter(f -> f.getAnimals().contains(an)).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

There could be empty sets for an animal in the case when none of the farms contains it, but that could be easily filtered

Comment: That works, but repeatedly iterating over the list is rather inefficient.

Comment: Well, it works in the same way as the original code: 4 animals are checked for 3 farms. So does any another code on this page. Mine just starts from different side, that made the code shorter and, in my humble opinion, easier for a reader.

Comment: It does *not* work like the original code. You are running through the entire list for each `Animal` that has been defined. The original code only runs through the sets of `Animal` values actually associated with `Farm` instances in the list. As a consequence, for `Animal` constants not currently used in any `Farm` in the `list`, your code produces a map entry with an empty list which the original code doesn’t. There are, by the way, at least five constants in `Animal`, but no-one ever said that only these five constants exist. Even with an empty `list`, your code will add all keys to the map.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's because I've made a short note about empty sets of the animals. And still, I see no problem with that.